# Iterando array que contém objetos/arrays aninhados

Tags: javascript, array

Estou precisando iterar um array que contém objetos, que por sua vez contém outros arrays.

Eu consegui fazer funcionar e extrair cada array de cada propriedade com esse código:

```js
const dados = [
  {
    backend: ['Ruby', 'Ruby on Rails'],
    frontend: ['html', 'css', 'javascript'],
    db: ['Sqlite3']
  },
  {
    backend: ['Ruby', 'Ruby on Rails'],
    frontend: ['html', 'css', 'javascript'],
    db: ['Sqlite3']
  }
];


dados.map( function (value){
  for (var chave in value){
    //console.log(value[chave]);
    console.log(chave);
    for (var i = 0; i < value[chave].length; i++){
      console.log(value[chave][i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Funcionou, mas achei meio confuso. Alguém teria alguma dica para melhorar?
Eu venho de Ruby, e Javascript esta me deixando doido!

Comment: Depende do que quer fazer com os dados. O uso de `map` não parece adequado, já que ele serve para transformar uma array em outra, não simplesmente iterar.

Comment: Como já dito acima, usar `map` **somente** para iterar [é errado](/q/426821/112052), pois a ideia do `map` é executar algo com os elementos do array e **retornar outro array** com os resultados (similar ao `map` do Ruby, inclusive). Se só quer iterar e fazer algo, e não quer outro array com os resultados do processamento, um `for` simples (algo como a resposta abaixo) já serve. Enfim, sem saber o que vc quer fazer, fica difícl dar qualquer dica...

Comment: Por fim, isso não é um array multidimensional (por isso tomei a liberdade de editar e mudar o título). Na verdade é um array que contém objetos, e cada um desses objetos contém 3 propriedades (backend, frontend e db), e o valor de cada uma dessas propriedades é outro array.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Pessoal!
Amo vcs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você deseja apenas iterar, como @bfavaretto disse em seu [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/541854/iterando-array-que-cont%C3%A9m-objetos-arrays-aninhados#comment972759_541854), o [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) não é o método mais adequado já que a mesmo retorna um novo array.

Assim seria um outro modo:

```js
const dados = [{backend: ['Ruby', 'Ruby on Rails'],frontend: ['html', 'css', 'javascript'],db: ['Sqlite3']},{backend: ['Ruby', 'Ruby on Rails'],frontend: ['html', 'css', 'javascript'],db: ['Sqlite3']}];

for (const obj of dados) {
  for (const arrays of Object.values(obj)) {
    console.log(arrays); // ['Ruby', 'Ruby on Rails'], etc
  }
}
```

[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) irá retornar

> um array contendo os valores das propriedades enumeradas do dado objeto.

Mais informações sobre o `Object.values` se você quiser saber mais sobre: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Comment: Editei o seu post na intenção de melhorar a qualidade. Se achar que fui muito invasivo a qualquer momento você pode reverter as edições clicando  em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/541857/revisions e reverter para uma versão anterior.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dados = [
  {
backend: ['Ruby', 'Ruby on Rails'],
frontend: ['html', 'css', 'javascript'],
db: ['Sqlite3']
  },
  {
backend: ['Ruby', 'Ruby on Rails'],
frontend: ['html', 'css', 'javascript'],
db: ['Sqlite3']
  }
];

dados.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
item.backend.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
console.log(item);
  });
});
```

Ola, nesse caso eu gosto de usar o metodo forEach, ele irá iterar todos os indices do array atraves de um callback, e para cada array filho, podes realizar um novo forEach.